# how to use digital ocean's kubernetes and set auto-scale?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, autoscaling

I'm working on kubernetes. Now I tried Digital Ocean's kubernetes which is very easy to install and access, but how can I install metric-server in it? how can I auto scale in kubernetes by DO?
Please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Metrics Server can be installed to your cluster with Helm:

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/metrics-server

```
helm init
helm upgrade --install metrics-server --namespace=kube-system stable/metrics-server
```

with RBAC enabled, see the more comprehensive instructions for installing Helm into your cluster:

https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md

If you wish to deploy without Helm, the manifests are available from the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/tree/master/deploy/1.8%2B

Comment: is there any other way to get metric server in my cluster? other than helm?

Comment: I cant clone GitHub repo, as DigitalOcean's kubernetes we have no access to the master node

Comment: You don't need access to the master node, you apply the manifests with `kubectl apply -f` just as you would with any other manifest.